# Javascript: compare string numbes above 10.0

Tags: javascript

After ajax query I have the next numbers:

```
var a = "5.20";
var b = "7.20";
var c = "11.20";
```

I have noticed that if compare numbers above `10.00` the condition is false. I do not understand why this happens

```
if (b > a) console.log("higher"); // true
if (c > b) console.log("higher"); // not true
```

I have solved the problem with next code (it should also work `parseFloat`)

```
if ((+c) > (+b)) console.log("higher"); // true
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You should never rely on a greater/lower than with strings.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: It happens because you are comparing strings which is based on lexicographical order in which "7" > "1"

Answer (score 3):

`"5" > "10"` for the same reason that `"m" > "ba"`. Strings are compared alphabetically (even if they contain digits) - or rather [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: very good explanation

Answer (score 0):

The variables are string type. Not integers.

```
typeof("5.20"); // OUTPUT: "string"
```

Remove the quotation marks:

```
var a = 5.20;
var b = 7.20;
var c = 11.20;
if (b > a) console.log("higher"); // true
if (c > b) console.log("higher"); // also true
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: I know, that's why in the headline I put 'string numbers'

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing two strings alphabetically. If you remove the quotes where you create the variables then you will have numbers and your code will work.

```
var a = 5.20;
var b = 7.20;
var c = 11.20;
```